# jQuery selector speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Is selecting by ID-only (or a single identifier) faster than when adding additional identifiers?

For example

`$('#element')`

vs

`$('#container #element')`

or even more specific:

`$('body div#container div#element')`

?

Comment: @john_doe: Not exactly, at least the third one [will get all `div` elements and then filter those with ID `element`](http://jsfiddle.net/dFC4k/1/). And even in second case [jQuery makes a test whether `#element` is descendant of `#container`](http://jsfiddle.net/dFC4k/).

Comment: @FelixKling: Then I've misread an article (I can't find...) and misinterpreted a comment in the sizzle source `// Take a shortcut and set the context if the root selector is an ID
// (but not if it'll be faster if the inner selector is an ID)` - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#element')` should be fastest, followed by `$('div')`.  These map to the native functions `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByTagName`.  Anything more complex has to go through complex scripting and document searching.

On everything but IE6, 7, and 8, `$('.class')` also map to the new `document.getElementsByClassName` function as well, but this is slower than the other two and still has to go through Sizzle if the browser doesn't support it.

Comment: what about if you already have an jQuery object and do a .find('#element')? IDs should be unique so it shouldn't really matter but I'm using backbone and rather not use global jQuery instead of view-bounded jQuery (which uses .find())

Answer (score 5):

Yes, selecting by ID only should be the fastest, because jQuery (or Sizzle) can directly use `getElementById`. Otherwise the rest of the selector has to be evaluated as well, right to left.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to use as few selectors as you can that will correctly identify the element(s) that you wish to process. For instance if `element` is a unique id (as it should be), then `#element` will uniquely specify it and anything else will be wasteful, both in parsing and processing overhead. (This goes equally for CSS style rules, of course, although in this case the optimal choice of selectors may be different than when using jQuery.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually calling

`document.getElementById("element");`

is fastest.

If you really want a jQuery object then call `$(document.getElementById("element"));`

[Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/by-id-vs-wrapped)